# Can't use WebStorm Live Edit after 2016.2 Update

Tags: webstorm, liveedit

Last night I've updated WebStorm to version 2016.2. When I tried to debug using Live Edit, my browser show the following URL instead of the regular one:

> chrome-extension://hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji/loading.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A65487%2F70-480%2FQuestionsAndAnswers.html

I already tried to reinstall Live Edit on WebStorm and reinstall the Chrome extension on my browser with no success.

Does anyone know how to fix this?